# VB6 project to Vb.net migration

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am migrating VB6 project to Vb.net and I have form has OCX grid, the grid displayed Ok, and I can double click on any rows and open the detail form but when I double click the first row to open form to Add new rows, I got "{System.ExecutionEngineException}" {System.Collections.EmptyReadOnlyDictionaryInternal} exception, please any one can help me?

The double click code in the DLL of OCX, 
this is the code that should call to Open the new form but it is not even hit this part of the code:

```
Private Sub ResultGrid1_addSelected(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As AxSET_ResultGrid.__ResultGrid_addSelectedEvent) Handles ResultGrid1.addSelected
    addSelected(mGridType, eventArgs.oUseExpandedSQL, eventArgs.oExpandedKeys, ResultGrid1, mDetailForm)
End Sub
```

Comment: `AddSelected` is not an event on a standard dot.Net grid. What it the control being used here.

Comment: BTW, several nice features of grids and types of standard grid did not make it's way to the dot.Net world, and still have not. I think just in the last version or so did they finally bring back something like the hierarchical flex grid. Man that thing was nice. You'll have to find some third-party controls and re-write.

Comment: Thank you Steve for the comment, I think the cause of the issue that empty string was passing as args to Addselected sub, It work fine now after I changed this Addselected sub to Rowselected sub.I am not expert in Dot Not but I agree with you, it is not fun to work with it.